# Single word for - discussing the answers of an examination

Tags: single-word-requests

Once an examination is over and the answer sheets have been evaluated, my university offers a session for the students to verify their marks by discussing it with the evaluators, by that way the students are convinced that they got fair marks. Of-course students can come forth and get their marks corrected if an answer is not evaluated well.

My question is - What is such a session called? Here it is popularly known as *crib session*, but while googling, I didn't see that word used in the aforementioned context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Canadian high school and university, we refer to this as *'Exam Review'*, or *'Final Grade Review'*.

By [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/review) *review* is the best word for the described situation

> **Review:** A formal assessment of something with the intention of instituting change if necessary.

I am also aware that some universities call this *'Exam Viewing'* as well, which is quite self explanatory, it allows one to see their exam.